# Sem retorno com shell_exec no PHP

Tags: php

Recentemente surgiu a necessidade de aproveitar algumas funções de um programa com linguagem pascal compilado com "fpc" no PHP, o mesmo executa perfeitamente pelo terminal no Debian, o programa é muito simples e é do tipo console, a chamada é feita da seguinte maneira passando como parâmetro um texto qualquer, ex: `./encrypt "HELLO"` e o resultado é uma linha de texto simples gerada pelo comando `writeln(func_encrypt('C',ParamStr(1)));`, logo após o programa é finalizado. Das formas que já tentei, nenhum retorno é exibido pelo PHP, nem resultado e nem erros. Tentei utilizando as seguintes funções:

```
$output = shell_exec('encrypt "HELLO"');
echo $output; //nenhum resultado

$output = exec('encrypt "HELLO"');
echo $output; //nenhum resultado

$output = system('encrypt "HELLO"');
echo $output; //nenhum resultado
```

Também tentei informando no parâmetro `'./encrypt "HELLO"'` e `'/caminho_completo/encrypt "HELLO"'` e por surpresa também nada acontece.

Utilizando qualquer uma das funções acima, o comando `date` mostra a saída perfeitamente.

Será que o erro está na forma como a saída do texto é exibida no programa?

Comment: O *php* tem permissão para executar o código pascal? Caso não tenha, basta utilizar o comando `sudo chmod +x /path/to/encrypt`. Você também pode usar os redirecionamento, por exemplo: `/path/to/encrypt 2>&1`

Comment: Acredito que não seja problema com permissão, anteriormente eu já tinha atribuído: `chmod 777 encrypt`...